# Name Active Layer in expression

Tags: qgis, sql, expression, atlas

I would like to produce an atlas of 5 blocks for 16 variables.
So for each atlas I display a layer who represent a variable.
For each map in atlas I'm able de set a title with display block name with something like that :

```
'NDVI ' + "block_name_field"
```

But I have 16 variables and I don't want to handwrite it. Is code like that possible ?

```
Active_layer_name + "block_name_field"
```

Comment: Is there a function like `@layer_name` available? So maybe `@layer_name + " block_name_field"`. Haven't really used Atlas myself so this is just a guess.

Comment: I tried it in expression editor. Preview shows atlas layer name and not variable layer. And in my title it finally displays nothing...

Answer (score 1):

In the plug-in Expressions Plus **FR** *(derived from the original from N. Woodrow)* you have a function called **NamePathActiveLayer** that almost does the job (you have at least file name of active layer ...)

**or** (better, i suppose) :

write your own expression, go in the expression dialog box, activate the **function editor tab** and try the following code :

```
    from qgis.core import *
    from qgis.gui import *
    from qgis.utils import iface

    @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='create_your_own_group')
    def ActiveLayerName(feature, parent):
      layer = iface.activeLayer()
      if layer != None :
      return layer.name()
```

You will have to save the code and the new function should be available (at qgis restart i think ...)

Comment: I can't find Expressions Plus FR. I have just N. Woodrow version. Have you more deposits than official deposit ?

Comment: u're right ... not sure the deposit is visible ...